# MVC 4, can't connect to SQL after publishing to Azure WebSites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC 4 from Internet template with simple membership provider. Site is running in Azure WebSites and SQL is also in Azure.

Sadly, I got error every time after I publish new version.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

I figured it out, that if I remove cookies from my browser the site is start working again.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:
I found exactly same problem [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964004/authentication-problems-after-publishing-mvc-4-app-to-azure)

Suggested solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/12991835/1585397 is "somehow" working. Sometimes is, sometimes isn't..

Comment: are you, by any chance, storing a database object in a session?

Comment: no, I'm not storing a database object in a session.

Comment: Fresh out of ideas then :).

Comment: Have you checked your connection string? If you're using SQL Azure, you can point to that db in dev and test it that way.

Comment: yes. Connection string looks fine. (has to be, because it is working after cookies are deleted)