# Two Chrome sessions on the same machine - one will connect to our Azure website, the other "unable to connect to SQL Server database"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

We have a problem with an Azure website that intermittently fails with this error:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]

and

> HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

By intermittent I mean that you can start a new browser session and it'll be OK again, then later in the day it'll fail.

There's lots of advice online for this error but it all involves setting up your connectionstring correctly or fixing roleManager or membership in the web.config. None of these solutions would seem to be compatible with *intermittent* errors on our site (ie. if our connectionstring or web.config were incorrect presumably the site would *always* fail).

It may be relevant that we had an existing site `foo.azurewebsites.net` and codebase and we switched to `bar.azurewebsites.net` and substantially changed the codebase (though starting with the same original files). We've also added some simple **Role** admin code. Is it possible that because of caching the new site is sometimes trying to connect to the old site's database (now gone)?

But we've had one user laboriously help us out, deleting from his cache anything which was relating to the "old" site ... which fixed his problem ... but next day the problem returned for him.

**Update**
Recently I was sat here with 2 side by side Chrome browser sessions (different user logins), hitting the site again and again. One session was getting 100% error, the other 0% errors. But I can't reproduce it now. No errors at all for me. But users still saying they're getting a tremendous error rate of 80% to 90% of the time.

**Update**
It's down again this morning (for one browser session), however many times I try to refresh. A different browser window/identity I fired up alongside it is fine.

**Update**
Perhaps I have the same problem asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964004/authentication-problems-after-publishing-mvc-4-app-to-azure). Deleting cookies seems to fix it in my case, just as Mark Heath documents. Currently trying the answer Mark posted himself there to see if it helps my situation too.

Comment: Let me just double-check: if you have 2 different browsers opened, both opening bar.azurewebsites.net, but logged in as different application users. Then one of the sessions will stay connected to the DB, another session will *always* fail to connect? Is that related to a user? Or is second session *sometimes* fail to connected to DB?

Comment: @trailmax i was sat here a coupla days ago with 2 side by side browser sessions as described, hitting the site again and again. 1 session was getting 100% error, the other 0% error. but i can't reproduce it now. no errors at all for me. but users still saying they're getting tremendous error rate 80% to 90%.

Comment: Are you doing something special in DB Context? How do you provide connection strings? Any chance of DbContext source code?

Comment: @trailmax just the out-of-the-box stuff for UsersContext. all auto-generated by visual studio. e.g.: `Public Class UsersContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("DefaultConnection")
    End Sub

    Public Property UserProfiles As DbSet(Of UserProfile)
End Class

Comment: I read the answer below and the comments above.  It seems to me you should start logging exceptions (and general logging) somewhere because right now your users are quoting 80% and 90% error rates but you have no data to confirm it.  Plus it will help you troubleshoot the issue and be able to provide documentation to Azure support if that is the case.  I think better metrics on the errors would really help you.  If you are desperate try deploying to a cloud service instead of azure websites so then you can terminal service in and see if the request fails there too.

Comment: @hawbsl I have been having this exact same issue for about 3 months. I contacted MS and they told me to buy a support contract :(
My problem is also intermittent, however when it starts to fail it fails for everyone. Restarting the website will get it to connect to SQL again for 10 minutes or so (also variable) then failure again. Sometimes the issue goes away for a week - then it comes back and kills the app for 2-3 days, then goes away again... I also originally had my app on a different Azure host/region, then moved it and the problems began (SQL has always been on the same box however).

Answer (score 3):

**Presuming you are using Entity Framework**

**Warning**: this works only in EF6+. If you are in EF5 and have this problem, consider updating - it is easy.

If you have intermittent database connection problems in Azure, you should implement retry policy. You can do it via `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy`. This is described here in detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.aspx

Here is how to enable this:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration 
{ 
    public MyConfiguration() 
    { 
        SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy()); 
    } 
}
```

and then you'll need to decorate your DbContext with configuration attribute:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyConfiguration))]
public class MyDbContext : DbContext 
{
// blah
}
```

If you have manually initiated transactions, you'll need to disable retry-policy. For that you'll need to change MyConfiguration to look like this:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration 
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => SuspendExecutionStrategy
              ? (IDbExecutionStrategy)new DefaultExecutionStrategy()
              : new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))); 
    }

    public static bool SuspendExecutionStrategy
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool?)CallContext.LogicalGetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy") ?? false;
        }
        set
        {
            CallContext.LogicalSetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy", value);
        }
    } 
}
```

And wrap your transaction calls like this:

```
MyConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = true;
// start transaction
// do transaction stuff here
// commit/rollback transaction
MyConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = false;
```

Code shamelessly stolen from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/data/dn307226.aspx

Comment: we are using EF5, when you say it's easy to update, can you point to some guidelines for updating.

Comment: Simples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx. Only beware, if you run migrations with EF6, it changes the structure of __MigrationHistory table, so there is no way back to EF5. I've blogged about update gotcha here: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/moving-from-entity-framework-5-to-entity-framework-6-and-back-or-could-not-determine-storage-version/

Comment: thanks trailmax, mmm. a couple of things that make me worried about implementing this throughout our application for potentially no gain:

Comment: 1) we almost never never see this error (and we're hitting it/testing it a lot), whereas the pool of users we have say they see this "most of the time", some of them say "90% of the time" which doesn't make it seem like an occasionally flaky behaviour WITHIN Azure, more like something to do with caching on their devices

Comment: if it is 100% for some users, then it is not Azure then, so discard my suggestion.

Comment: 2) on the occasion that our app fails with this error it will sit waiting for quite a long time before failing (it never fails _instantly_) giving the impression it is trying to do some kind of retry ... no?

Comment: re earlier comment, sorry 90% is probably more accurate. i don't think we have anyone feedback that they're "never" successful

Comment: 2) it would not fail instantly. If Sql Server is available, it connects instantly, but if there is a network issue, DbContext waits some timeout period for the server to reply. That is why it looks like it is retrying. It does not retry, just takes a long time to fail. I had same errors about 1-2 times per day, after I implemented retry policy, these errors gone away.

Comment: Is this the same as the EF "retry" mechanism advocated in some of the answers to similar questions? if so, i just don't see how it's gonna help, since I can "retry" manually via F5 as much as I like and it just doesn't help. It only rights itself when I completely close the browser and start again or come back later in the day.

Comment: yes, this is a retry. When I answered this I was not clear that you get errors 90% of times, so my answer is not relevant, which I said earlier